# unhandled socket.io url when connecting with ios socket.io client

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, socket.io, cloud9-ide

I have a problem connecting with my socket.io server hosted on cloud9 for testing purposes. Here is how my server looks like:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a client has been conected');
  socket.on('update', function(){
    console.log('receved an update :)');
  })
});


http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function(){
  var addr = http.address();
  console.log("Chat server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});
```

and here is my iOS client:

```
func initalSocketManager(){
    self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "https://applewatchnode-seven-ply.c9users.io")
    self.socket.connect()

    self.socket.on("connection") {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }
}
```

For any reason I'm not able to connect to my socket server. When I run my iOS app the server logs the following info:

```
info  - unhandled socket.io url
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your server code is a non-ssl HTTP listener on port 3000.  Your iOS client code is trying to connect over SSL (port 443).  They will never find each other.

Change your iOS code to

`http://applewatchnode-seven-ply.c9users.io:3000/`

Comment: Cloud9 serves apps on 8080 by default but also supports 8081 and 8082. You'll need to use one of those ports to get it working.